# GPIO pullups not working?

Tags: gpio, hardware, wiringpi

Sorry for the very basic question.  I am trying to set a built-in pullup on GPIO pins and it doesn't seem to be working.  Hardware is Pi 3B and 4B (I tried on both), OS is Raspbian 10 (buster). The wiringPi pin 0 (BCM pin 17) is not connected to anything:

```
% gpio mode 0 input 
% gpio mode 0 up 
% gpio read 0 
0 
%
```

Should this pin not be reading back a 1 due to the pull-up?  What am I missing?

Comment: Which model Pi? Which distribution?

Comment: Pi 4B and 3B.  I tried on both.  Current Raspbian (version 10 buster) OS.

Comment: You should edit your question and/or the tags to include that information.

Comment: Have you tried `gpio mode 0 in` instead of `input`? http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/ lists `in` as the command for reading a pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wiringPi pull-ups and pull-downs do not work on the Pi4B.  The ways the pulls work has changed in the new BCM2711 SoC used in the Pi4B.

See this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104312/setting-pull-up-pull-down-mode-doesnt-work-mostly).

As far as I know they do work correctly on the Pi3B (but I have not tested recently).

Answer (score 0):

set the pullups in config.txt
or use raspi-gpio command.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd explain how in more detail.

Comment: This link contains the info on how to set up gpio pins at boot time y /boot/config.txt file. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/gpio.md

Comment: other way that worked to me was explained at wiring.org.
cd /tmp
wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb

(http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/)

apliying this method you will end up with 2.62 version instead of 2.52. But I hope 2.62 will solve your problems and you will get everything working just using Gordon Henderson's great library. (Please do not send questions to his mail).

Comment: the third option si to use raspi-gpio tool.

The raspi-gpio tool is designed to help hack / debug BCM283x GPIO.
Running raspi-gpio with the help argument prints this help.
raspi-gpio can get and print the state of a GPIO (or all GPIOs)
and can be used to set the function, pulls and value of a GPIO.
raspi-gpio must be run as root.
Use:
  raspi-gpio get [GPIO]
OR
  raspi-gpio set <GPIO> [options]
OR
  raspi-gpio funcs [GPIO]
OR
  raspi-gpio raw

Comment: hope this may be useful for you. I' bored making quarantine here in Argentina!!!

Comment: can't set gpio21 (pin 40) even with raspi-gpio what I am doing wrong?